# Is it possible to write a Partitioned DataFrame into S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, partitioning, aws-glue

I have to write a Spark DataFrame into S3 bucket and it should create a separate parquet file for each partition.

Here is my code:

```
dynamicDataFrame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(
                       testDataFrame, glueContext , 
                       "dynamicDataFrame")

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                  frame = dynamicDataFrame,
                  connection_type = "s3",  
                  connection_options = {
                            "path": "s3://BUCKET_NAME/DIR_NAME",
                             "partitionKeys": ["COL_NAME"]
                  },
                  format = "parquet"
 )
```

When I specify *"partitionKeys": ["COL_NAME"]* option then Glue Job gets executed without any error but it does not create any file in S3.

And when I remove this "partitionKeys" option then it  creates 200 parquet files in S3(default No Of Partition is 200).
But I want to create partitions on the basis of a particular column.

So, is it possible to create partition wise parquet files in S3 while writing a DF in S3?

Note: I am using AWS resources i.e. AWS Glue.

Comment: It's definitely [possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html). Are you sure your `dynamicDataFrame` isn't empty? Do you use bookmarking?

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk Thanks for your response ... Yes, I am sure my dynamic DataFrame is not empty. But Yes I am using bookmarking

Comment: I removed Bookmarking but still I am not able to write partition  wise DF into S3..initially it creates a temp  directory and once job gets complete then it delete that temp dir too.

Comment: posting the solution might be beneficial for others. Also dataframe and dynamicframe works slightly different. Dataframe supports s3,so there is NO need to convert the dataframe to dynamic frame before writing to s3.

Answer (score 1):

R you sure partition column has data?

Do you find anything in glue logs

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write ...It was my mistake ..Actually, It was a logical error ..now its working fine